# SwiftUI When I use stroke in clipShape I got error

Tags: swiftui

I edited my question. I shared full code.

I want to bend the end points of the semicircle as in the 1st image. How can I do that ? I tried this code but got an unrelated error.
How can I soften the corners of a half circle?

I created a `customShape` but I couldn't get the look I wanted.

```
.clipShape(
           circle()
             .trim(from: 0.5, to: 1)
             .stroke(Color.red, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 30, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
```

**Error:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**ChartData Container:**

```
class ChartDataContainer : ObservableObject {
    @Published var chartData =
        [ChartData(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.4932718873, blue: 0.4739984274, alpha: 1)), percent: 8, value: 0),
         ChartData(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.8323456645, blue: 0.4732058644, alpha: 1)), percent: 15, value: 0),
         ChartData(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4508578777, green: 0.9882974029, blue: 0.8376303315, alpha: 1)), percent: 32, value: 0),
         ChartData(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.476841867, green: 0.5048075914, blue: 1, alpha: 1)), percent: 45, value: 0)]
  
    func calc(){
        var value : CGFloat = 0
        
        for i in 0..<chartData.count {
            value += chartData[i].percent
            chartData[i].value = value
        }
    }
}
```

**Custom Shape:**

```
struct CustomShape: View {
  var body: some View {
    HalfCircle()
      .stroke(.red, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 30, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
      .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
  }
}

struct CustomShape_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    CustomShape()
  }
}

struct HalfCircle: Shape {
  func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    var path = Path()
    
    path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY), radius: rect.height/2, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 180), clockwise: true)
    
    
    return path
  }
}
```

**Code:**

```
struct HalfDonutChart : View {
  @ObservedObject var charDataObj = ChartDataContainer()
  @State var indexOfTappedSlice = -1
  var body: some View {
    
    ZStack {
      ZStack {
        ForEach(0..<charDataObj.chartData.count) { index in
          Circle()
            .trim(from: 0.5, to: 1)
            .trim(from: index == 0 ? 0.0 : charDataObj.chartData[index-1].value/100, to: charDataObj.chartData[index].value/100)
            .stroke(charDataObj.chartData[index].color,lineWidth: 30)
            .onTapGesture {
              indexOfTappedSlice = indexOfTappedSlice == index ? -1 : index
            }
            .scaleEffect(index == indexOfTappedSlice ? 1.1 : 1.0)
            .animation(.spring())
        }
        
        
        
        if indexOfTappedSlice != -1 {
          Text(String(format: "%.2f", Double(charDataObj.chartData[indexOfTappedSlice].percent))+"%")
            .font(.title)
        }
      }
      .mask(
        CustomShape()
      )

      .frame(width: 200, height: 250)
      .padding()
      .onAppear() {
        self.charDataObj.calc()
    }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `mask` instead

Comment: I tried sir. No solution.

Comment: You cannot mix the topic of view and shape, then hoping Xcode would ignore it, after  using clipShape, you are allowed to give a shape not a view. with adding trim or stroke to shape you are modifying it to some view, you can create a custom shape with the result you want, then you can gave that shape to clipShpae.

Comment: Ps: You can solve the issue with mask as well. in that case you do not need clipShape.

Comment: Needed minimal reproducible example, provided code is not compilable and not testable.

Comment: I see same image as 1st one but in red color. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I drew the first picture with sketch. here to show.

Comment: @Asperi Sir. did you check my code ?